# Google Sheets search between two dates and give Event Name

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i got stuck with my event sheet and need help.

I want to write a formula that looks if dates of guest are between dates of an event and give the right event number to the right person.

| Last Name | First Name | Start | End | Event ? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Spider | Man | 13.10.2021 | 14.10.2021 |  |
| Tom | Cruise | 14.10.2021 | 16.10.2021 |  |
| Bruce | Wayne | 12.10.2021 | 14.10.2021 |  |

| Event | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 13.10.2021 | 14.10.2021 |
| Blue | 14.10.2021 | 15.10.2021 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are in Deutschland. Try

```
=textjoin(char(10);"";query(G:I;"select G where H<=DATE'"&TEXT(D2;"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and I>=DATE'"&TEXT(C2;"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' ";0))
```

[image]

Comment: First, thank you so much for your time to write the formula for me! That is so kind from you!!! BIG Thanks!!!!

Comment: Do you perhaps know a way to extract the excess days before or after an event with the formula? So that if his stay lasts 3 days, but the event starts on the same day as his arrival, he is assigned to the event from the arrival and does not appear at an event afterwards, even if his departure would still match the date?

Comment: Can you provide a simple spreadsheet with some examples and the output you expect ?